# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 error in M1Pro macbook

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, apple-silicon

I am trying to get my VS Code working on my M1Pro Macbook Pro when writing in C.
I wrote a very simple code as follows:

test.h

```
#ifndef __TEST_H__
#define __TEST_H__

#include <stdio.h>

void opti (int *a);

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("Type: ");

    opti(&a);
    printf("Input value read : a = %d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

test.c

```
#include "test.h"


void opti (int *a)
{
    scanf("%d", a);
}
```

However, I get this error from the VS Code terminal:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_opti", referenced from:
      _main in main-498fc7.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this issue?
I can run this exact code when all code is in main.c.
But when I add test.c, this problem occurs.

Comment: Could you add your compilation command? eg "gcc main.c test.c .etc.etc"

Comment: Thank you guys, I didn't use the compilation command, but used run in VS Code!

Answer (score 1):

instead of running it through the VSCode run, use compilation commands such as:

```
gcc -o main main.c test.c
```